# How to export comment fields (or other settings) with Features?

Tags: entities, comments, features, importing-exporting, workflows

If I export a content type that has fields specified in the **comment** of the content type the fields of the comment are not exported.

How do I export those fields that I specified in the comment?

(In my case a have a Workflow status field specified in the comment)

Answer (score 2):

I Managed to do this with the help of the **Strongarm** module.

In the variables table there are fields like:

comment_xxxx_xx_[content_type_name_here]

for example: 
field_bundle_settings_comment__comment_node_my_content_type
comment_default_per_page_my_content_type
..etc

I just selected all of them. It would be better of course to work out what is stored where.

Also in Features in **field instances** I found fields like:
comment-comment_node_my_content_type-comment_body
..

In Features **field_base** I found something called comment_body

Exporting those seemed to be everything. 
(Not too convenient to hunt fields and whatnot and maybe miss something..)

Answer (score 0):

user3027622 - thank you - I would like to add to your response a little, to explain how this problem can be solved using drush.

I also found that the Comment fields (in particular, the order in which the fields were displayed) were not being exported.

I did this to solve the problem.

```
# see which component types are available
drush fc

# search for components we want to export
drush fc variable | grep comment
drush fc field_instance | grep comment

# export the components to my feature
drush fe myfeature variable:field_bundle_settings_comment__comment_node_partner_video_page variable:field_bundle_settings_comment__comment_node_video_page field_instance:comment-comment_node_partner_video_page-comment_body field_instance:comment-comment_node_video_page-comment_body
```